# Symfony app working perfectly on local but 500 on server

Tags: git, symfony, azure, assets

I am working on a small project using symfony2!, heres the thing i have my "site" running locally and all is working as it should!

so then i push it up to the server, i use git and basically Microsoft azure updates the site from my branch but now all im getting is a 500! i think i did use symlinks to include my assets? would this cause the error on the server? (I do my Dev on linux mint)

Im really not sure whats causing this 500 error and im not sure on how to debug it myself??

any suggestions would be great!!

Comment: Probably it's a permission issue. Tail the application log (`tail -f app/logs/prod.log`), the web server's log and make the request again. The error should show up on one of the logs. Then update the question with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for sure the symlinks. Azure Web Apps runs on Windows, which is an OS which does not understand Linux symlinks (it has another concept - junctions, but it will not work on Azure web apps anyway). 
Try to get rid of the symlinks and restructure your repo. If everything is a "hard" link (path in repo), it will work.